# What adapter do I need: Philips Headset + Samsung S4 mini duos

Tags: samsung, headset

I would like to use the microphone of my Philips headset (SHO9567GB/10, iPod compatible) with my Samsung S4 mini Duos (i9192). Right now, the headset is only recognised as headphone. What kind of adapter do I need?

Answer (score 0):

The in-line-mic only works for compatible Apple products. Apple always has something different than the standard and most Android devices use the opposite. I would like to see an adapter, but it would probably use an Apple patent. I think you're out of luck, but I'll update this if I find anything in the future. Next headphone pair you buy, I recommend you looking up if it's fully Android compatible.

P.S. If you in-line-buttons (volume and track control) to work, their are apps that convert one Android compatible button to work like the other few buttons using double clicking them. I recommend [Headset Button Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kober.headset) I am warning you that they get annoying because you have to have the play-pause button working as well as be able to spam the play button a number of times to get it to do volume-up for example.